# How to write a URL rule in Yii framework?

Tags: yii, yii-routing, yii-url-manager

```
<?php echo CHtml::link($value->title, array(Yii::app()->createUrl('forum/thread', array('id'=>$value->thread_id)))); ?>
```

i got a link

> forum/thread/2

in my urlManager rules `'thread/<id:\d+>' => 'forum/thread',`

how to change the rule and method createUrl?

```
createUrl('any-value/forum/thread', array('id'=>$value->thread_id))
```

to get in url

> forum/any-value/thread/2 or forum/php-for-newbies/thread/2

I am sorry for my english, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL Manager rule should look like this:

```
'forum/<title:\w+>/thread/<id:\d+>' => 'forum/thread', //make sure this is listed first so it has priority
'thread/<id:\d+>' => 'forum/thread',
```

Then in your controller you would have this:

```
public function actionThread($id,$title=null) {
    //$title will contain title from url if sent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`'forum/any-value/thread/<id:\d+>' => 'any-value/forum/thread',`

and with this: 
`createUrl('any-value/forum/thread', array('id'=>$value->thread_id))`
So you should get `forum/any-value/thread/2`

that should work!

But If you are inside the module called `forum` then you would do like that:

`'any-value/thread/<id:\d+>' => 'any-value/forum/thread',`

and with this: 
`createUrl('any-value/forum/thread', array('id'=>$value->thread_id))`